# Use `shinycssloaders::withSpinner` to cover more than one input

Tags: r, shiny, shinycssloaders

I am using `shinycssloaders` to show loading animation. There are multiple inputs on the page which are loaded from the server. These inputs are also dependent on each other.

In the below example I have used a reactive object to create such dependency. First the table is displayed and only when the calculation of table is completed (`rv$a <- 1`) plot can be completed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(
    withSpinner(tableOutput('data')),
    withSpinner(plotOutput('plot'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(a = NULL)
  
  output$data <- renderTable({
    #Some long calculation here, using Sys.sleep for simplicity
    Sys.sleep(2)
    rv$a <- 1
    head(mtcars)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(rv$a)
    #Some long calculation here, using Sys.sleep for simplicity
    Sys.sleep(2)
    plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works fine but it shows 2 loaders, one for table and other one for plot. I want to combine these 2 loaders and show only 1 loading animation which covers the entire page combining table and plot. Also loading should end only after all the calculation is done i.e after plot calculation.

I have tried putting table and plot in a `div` and use spinner on div but it did not work and gave a blank page.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  withSpinner(div(
    tableOutput('data'),
    plotOutput('plot')
  ))
)
```

Does anybody have a solution to this? Is this possible using some different package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tagList()` function, which creates a list of the tags allowing the `shinycssloaders` package to wrap all the inputs within it in one go.

So the ui will look like the following:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  withSpinner(tagList(tableOutput('data'),
          plotOutput('plot')))
)
```

> Just some extra information for the animation. You can all change the style of the animation such as the the type, color, size , etc by adding these as arguments to the withSpinner(). Check the [withSpinner()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinycssloaders/versions/1.0.0/topics/withSpinner) RDocumentation.

Comment: Thanks, this works for the example shared but in my actual example I am not able to make it work. In my real example, there are many more components in `ui` which I put in`tagList` but spinner doesn't show up. Do you know if there is any limit on components that can be included in `tagList` ? Nonetheless, thank you for your help. I'll ask a new question if I am not able to resolve it by myself.